# Sequelize - hasMany() - setter resets previous rows' foreign-key to null

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

One of the features of my app is to check from where someone accessed a link based on a query param.

Based on this, I have the following code that registers the click in a `Clicks` table; then I set the foreign-key to the `URL` that is in another table; lastly I set the foreign-key to the Origin that is also in another table (`Origins`).

Everything works fine if I used belongsTo instead of hasMany but on Clicks and `click.setUrl(url)` instead of `url.setClick(click)` though.

```
  const urlCode = req.params.urlCode
  const org = req.query.org
  let err

  try {
    const url = await Urls.findOne({ where: { urlCode: urlCode } })
    const origin = await Origins.findOne({ where: { abbr: org } })

    if (url === null) {
      res.redirect(`${process.env.WEB_URL}/not-found`)
      err = { code: 404, msg: 'URL Not found' }
      throw err
    }

    const click = await Clicks.create()
    click.setOrigin(origin)
*   url.setClick(click)

    res.redirect(url.originalUrl)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(err.code).send(err.msg)
  }
```

---

### Problem

Here is the output. The last 2 lines are related to the marked line above with an asterix.
**The problem is that on the second line, the setter resets the previous id to NULL.**

```
Executing (default): UPDATE `Clicks` SET `originId`=NULL,`updatedAt`='2019-06-10 11:05:16' WHERE `id` = 5
Executing (default): UPDATE `Clicks` SET `UrlId`=NULL,`updatedAt`='2019-06-10 11:05:16' WHERE `id` IN (4)
Executing (default): UPDATE `Clicks` SET `UrlId`=1,`updatedAt`='2019-06-10 11:05:16' WHERE `id` IN (5)
```

---

### Models:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Urls = sequelize.define('Urls', {
    originalUrl: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    shortUrl: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    urlCode: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
  })

  Urls.associate = function (models) {
    Urls.hasMany(models.Clicks, { as: 'click' })
  }

  return Urls
}
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Clicks = sequelize.define('Clicks')

  Clicks.associate = function (models) {
    Clicks.belongsTo(models.Origins, { as: 'origin' })
  }
  return Clicks
}
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Origins = sequelize.define('Origins', {
    origin: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    abbr: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  })

  return Origins
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

```
    const click = await Clicks.create()
    click.setOrigin(origin)
//- url.setClick(click)
  + url.addClick(click)

    res.redirect(url.originalUrl)
```